# MySQL trigger after insert with insert and delete instructions does not work properly

Tags: mysql, trigger, insert, delete

I have the following trigger created in phpMyAdmin:

`Table: tb_agenda
 Time: AFTER
 Event: INSERT`

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tb_realizacao (dt_agenda,
                               titulo, 
                               titulo_en, 
                               descricao, 
                               descricao_en, 
                               dt_cadastro)
        SELECT  dt_agenda,
                titulo,
                titulo_en,
                descricao,
                descricao_en,
                dt_cadastro
        FROM tb_agenda
        WHERE dt_agenda < NOW();

    DELETE FROM tb_agenda
     WHERE dt_agenda < NOW();
END
```

The trigger works 50%. The `INSERT` instruction works perfectly but the `DELETE` one doesn't execute. I tried to execute it in the SQL panel and it works fine.

Comment: Hmmm...  I wonder if there could _sometimes_ be two different values for `NOW()`.

Comment: just a question. Why are you executing `SELECT` statement in an after insert trigger? And Also it maybe better to provide the full trigger body.

Comment: @RickJames there shouldn't be: *[`NOW()` returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger, `NOW()` returns the time at which the function or triggering statement began to execute.) This differs from the behavior for `SYSDATE()`, which returns the exact time at which it executes.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)*

Comment: Good.  I'm at a loss to explain what you are experiencing.

Comment: So, no ideas why the DELETE isn't executed?

Comment: If you are trying to `DELETE` the row whose `INSERT` caused the Trigger to fire; that won't work -- The `INSERT` does not happen until the Trigger finishes.  That is, the `DELETE` did run, but found nothing to delete.

Comment: Are you trying to "Create an Insert trigger to automatically move records to a different table".  If so, state that in the question.  If not, then please explain the intent of the trigger.

Comment: I have the table `tb_agenda` that everytime it's populated with new data, the trigger inserts into `tb_realizacao` the data from `tb_agenda` which `dt_agenda` (date) is less than `NOW()`, then exclude these old data from `tb_agenda`. Summarizing, the `tb_agenda` is the next events that will happen, and `tb_realizacao` is the events that already happened.

Comment: If I create a trigger for `tb_realizacao`, when adding a new data only one from `tb_agenda` is added into the other table, not to mention the DELETE doesn't work. I don't know what to do.

Comment: On a side note, you should not use INSERT SELECT as this will cause a lock on all of the SELECTED ROWS. As noted by others the DELETE will also cause huge rollback segments potentially. It is better to do an INSERT with a seperate select from a CURSOR. It is also better to DELETE with a limit until no more rows can be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger tries to do something that cannot be done in MySQL. You cannot use an SQL statement (DELETE, in your case) on the table that is associated to the trigger. You will get an error like this:

```
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 't' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

You are probably using MyISAM for your table. The DELETE does not cause a rollback, because the engine is not transactional. If you switch to InnoDB (which is usually the best choice) you will notice that the trigger and the original INSERT will completely fail.